Importing pdfs and organising a two level table of contents
I'm trying to import some lecture pdf files into a singular LaTeX document and organise them into the following structure:
Week 1:

Lecture 1: 
Lecture 2: 
Lecture 3: 

Week 2:

Lecture 4: 
Lecture 5: 
Lecture 6: 

And so on... With a correctly structured table of contents and identical bookmarks list so that I can quickly navigate and refer to lectures and their content within my pdf viewer.
My issues/requirements are:

I don't want section or subsection headings outside of the table of contents as I would like each imported lecture pdf to appear one after another within the document to save space/scrolling.
I would like each hyperlink in the table of contents to refer to the first page of each of the imported pdfs and not a weird position further down from the top of the linked page (had this issue when using the pdfpages option addtotoc).

My current document looks as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \includepdf[pages=-]{lecture1.pdf}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{lecture2.pdf}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{lecture3.pdf}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{lecture4.pdf}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{lecture5.pdf}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{lecture6.pdf}
\end{document}

Any ideas?
Edit:
In terms of hyperlinks/bookmarks, the below example works as I'd like it to, however, I need to generate a table of contents based off of this (note: have only imported a single pdf for this to be a working example).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
    \includepdf[link,pages=1-6]{example-image-a4-numbered}
    \bookmark[level=1,dest=example-image-a4-numbered.pdf.1]{Week 1}
    \bookmark[level=2,dest=example-image-a4-numbered.pdf.1]{Lecture 1}
    \bookmark[level=2,dest=example-image-a4-numbered.pdf.2]{Lecture 2}
    \bookmark[level=2,dest=example-image-a4-numbered.pdf.3]{Lecture 3}
    \bookmark[level=1,dest=example-image-a4-numbered.pdf.4]{Week 2}
    \bookmark[level=2,dest=example-image-a4-numbered.pdf.4]{Lecture 4}
    \bookmark[level=2,dest=example-image-a4-numbered.pdf.5]{Lecture 5}
    \bookmark[level=2,dest=example-image-a4-numbered.pdf.6]{Lecture 6}
\end{document}


welcome! you can use the page command (ish - see the doc) option to add a phantom section/subsection and a toc entry. the trick is to create a command which redefines itself so it is only executed on the first page. you've not provided code anybody but you can run for testing. consider using pdfs which are part of standard tex distributions.

You raise a good point, what pdfs are included with a standard text distribution? I'll look into the page command.

try e.g. \includepdf[pages=-]{example-image-a4-numbered} but substitute letter or whatever if you don't want a4. those samples have 12 pages, so you could just add one three or four times. (you want them all the same paper size, I assume.) these are from the mwe package and are handily in tex's input path i.e. they are in the latex tree and not the doc tree.

Thanks. I've gone ahead and added a partially working example.

I recommend using a custom inclusion command which wraps \includepdf with the settings you need.

\compstudypdf[<options>]{<filename>} is a basic wrapper which allows you to set some options, if desired, before including the PDF <filename>.pdf and adding an entry to the contents.
 ` recognises the following keys:

title={<title>} (you can skip the braces if <title> is simple enough, but it never hurts to include them and they are sometimes needed e.g. if <title> includes a comma, for example. The default is ?? just to ensure there's something, but I assume you would always want to use this key.
level=<level> is the level in the contents hierarchy and defaults to section. Use subsection for the next level down.
options=<key-value list> takes a list of options to pass onto pdfpages when calling \includepdf. I've set default options for pages=- and you shouldn't try to use pagecommand, but most other options are fair game. Again, you might not need to use this at all. But you might sometimes want to skip a page, for example, or specify some other feature.



The output is decidedly ugly - partly because hyperref produces fairly ugly hyperlinks by default, partly because it doesn't look great to add a subsubsection with no subsection and partly because the brightly coloured pages of the included PDFs are somewhat eye-watering1.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{bookmark}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726918/
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \compstudy_includepdf:nn
{
  \includepdf[#1]{#2}
}
\cs_new:Nn \compstudy_lectures_includepdf:nn
{
  \def\makethisstyle{\addcontentsline{toc}{\l_compstudy_toclevel_tl}{\l_compstudy_tocline_tl}}
  \def\makedynstyle{\makethisstyle\thispagestyle{empty}\global\let\makethisstyle\relax}
  \phantomsection
  \compstudy_includepdf:nn
  {
    pagecommand={\makedynstyle},
    #1,
  }{#2}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \compstudy_lectures_includepdf:nn { V }
\NewDocumentCommand \compstudypdf { O {title={??}} m }
{
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { compstudy } { level=section, #1 }
  \compstudy_lectures_includepdf:Vn \l_compstudy_pdfopts_tl { #2 }
  \group_end:
}
\keys_define:nn { compstudy }
{
  title .tl_set:N = \l_compstudy_tocline_tl,
  title .initial:V = \c_empty_tl,
  level .tl_set:N = \l_compstudy_toclevel_tl,
  level .initial:n = {section},
  options .tl_set:N = \l_compstudy_pdfopts_tl,
  options .initial:V = \c_empty_tl,
}

\includepdfset{%
  pages=-,
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newgeometry{top=0pt,headheight=0pt,headsep=0pt,vscale=1}
\compstudypdf[title=A]{example-image-a4-numbered}
\compstudypdf[title=B,level=subsection]{example-image-a4-numbered}
\compstudypdf[title={Sealing Wax, Cabbages and Kings}]{example-image-a4-numbered}
\compstudypdf[title={$x^2$}]{example-image-a4-numbered}
\compstudypdf[title={\emph{Reuctio} Arguments}]{example-image-a4-numbered}
\compstudypdf[title=C,level=subsubsection]{example-image-a4-numbered}
\end{document}

1At least, this is my excuse for not wrestling Okular for one of the grainy images it reluctantly yields these days.

Thanks cfr! I have tried using your code for my use case, however, I think the issue I'm having with hyperlinks is that they are taking me to the phantom section which is located somewhere down the page rather than at the top of the page, which is the same issue I was having with addtotoc within the pdfpages package. Your solution seems to be very similar to how that option works. Regardless, I'm learning a lot about LaTeX just by reading your code, so thank you.

@compstudy it doesn't take me right to the top. it takes me to roughly where the text block would start i.e. so the top of the text block is roughly at the top of my viewer's window. I've never used the addtotoc option, though I can't remember why not. if it takes you half way down the page I don't know what to say. maybe a viewer issue? does it happen with my exact code or only when you try to use it in your real document? if the former, I'm guessing viewer-dependent. if the latter, presumably something else. (is the text block and paper size correct?)

I'm on a Mac and using the Preview app, maybe that's why. However, because the imported pdfs have content right at the top of the page, having the hyperlink take me further down means I miss titles, etc. I've added a working example to my original post that might show the difference. If I can manually construct a table of contents, I should be there. I may just end up writing another program to automate the LaTeX code based on the files I have in directories but I really do like your custom commands.

@compstudy so I wonder what would happen if you added \usepackage[top=0pt,headheight=0pt,headsep=0pt,vscale=1]{geometry}. does that make any difference?

@compstudy otherwise you could maybe add a target at the very top of the page ....

Yeah that works for the hyperlinks, however, if I could get it to start doing that after the table of contents I think this would be an okay solution.

@compstudy please see edit. if that works, I'd load geometry with whatever you want for the toc (or just the defaults) and then use \newgeometry after the table of contents.

That works perfectly, thanks for your help.
